# How to save data in django models taken from bootstrap form?

Tags: django, forms, model

I'm new in Django and now I'm working on my first project.

I created model 'nom' to store data and also bootstrap form in html temlplate.
My question is how can I save data in my model after clicking submit button in my form in html.
All answers i have found recommended me to create Form as class.
Is any easy way to use data from my form?
Thanks

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
       body { margin: 40px }

        .my-container {
        border: 1px solid green}

        .my-row {
        border: 2px solid blue}

        .my-col {
        border: 2px solid red}
        btn-primary { margin-left: 50px}

        .align-right {

        text-align: center;
        border: 0;
      }

    </style>
</head>
<body>




<div class="container my-container">
    <form  action="{% url 'home' %}"  method="Post">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <div class= "row my-row">
              <div class="col-3 my-col">

                          <input type="number" placeholder="0" name="nom200" size="1" />

              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if liczba %}
                           {{ liczba }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>

              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if ls %}
                           {{ ls }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class= "row my-row">
              <div class="col-3 my-col">

                          <input type="number" placeholder="0" name="nom100" size="1" />

              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if liczba1 %}
                           {{ liczba1 }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if ls1 %}
                           {{ ls1 }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class= "row my-row">
              <div class="col-3 my-col">

                          <input type="number" placeholder="0" name="nom50" size="1" />

              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if liczba3 %}
                           {{ liczba3 }}

                           {% endif %}
                       </span></h3>

              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary" name="superowo"> {% if ls3 %}
                           {{ ls3 }}

                           {% endif %}

                       </span></h3>
              </div>
          </div>
                  <div class= "row my-row">
              <div class="col-3 my-col">



              </div>
              <div class="col my-col">
                       <h3><span class="badge badge-secondary"> {% if suma %}
                           {{ suma }}

                           {% endif %}
                       </span></h3>

              </div>
          </div>

              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" href="{% url 'home'%}" name="print_btn">
              <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="{% url 'some_view'%}" >Do PDF</a>
           <div class="align-right">

      </div>

    </form>


   </div>



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class nom (models.Model):
    nom200=models.Field(max_length=200)
    nom100 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nom50 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import slownie
from .models import nom



def home (request):

    ls=''
    ls1=''
    ls3=''
    liczba= request.POST.get("nom200")
    liczba1=request.POST.get("nom100")
    liczba3=request.POST.get("nom50")
    if liczba and liczba.isdigit():
        liczba=int(liczba)*200
        ls=slownie.slownie(int(liczba))
    if liczba1 and liczba1.isdigit():
        liczba1=int(liczba1)*100
        ls1=slownie.slownie(int(liczba1))
    if liczba3 and liczba3.isdigit():
        liczba3=int(liczba3)*50
        ls3=slownie.slownie(int(liczba3))
    suma=0
    if liczba1 and liczba and liczba3:
        suma=int(liczba)+int(liczba1)+int(liczba3)
    nom200=liczba
    nom100=liczba1
    nom50=liczba3

    return render(request, 'home.html',{'liczba':liczba,'liczba1':liczba1,'liczba3':liczba3,
                                        'suma':suma,
                                        'ls':ls,
                                        'ls1':ls1,
                                        'ls3':ls3})
```

Answer (score 1):

You save it in a model:

```
# …
nom200=liczba
nom100=liczba1
nom50=liczba3

nom.objects.create(
    nom200=nom200
    nom100=nom100
    nom50=nom50
)
```

Normally Django models are however written in *PerlCase*, so `Nom`, instead of <s>`nom`</s>, this is often a good idea to prevent name clashes with *object*, that often use the name of the model, but in *snake_case*.